# Gregorian Calender Auto adds to Month

Tags: java

I am trying to get client entrance and exit date and see if they are valid.
but random days are added to month with each time I run the program. the month can be 43 for example after I entered 03. can you tell me why ?

```
public void makeNewReservation() throws ParseException {

        // Enter informations
        boolean error=true;
        boolean dateOK=false;
        String date_sortiee="";
        String date_entree="";
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);


        while(error){
            //take date of checkin and checkout and verify if they are OK

            System.out.println("Single room selected ? dd/MM/yyyy");
            System.out.println("Date de Entree?");
            in=new Scanner(System.in);

        //  date_entree = in.next();    

            System.out.println("Date de Entree? dd/MM/yyyy");
            date_entree = in.next();
            String[] test = date_entree.split("/");
            int day = Integer.parseInt(test[0]);
            int Month = Integer.parseInt(test[1]);

            int year = Integer.parseInt(test[2]);
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            GregorianCalendar checkin= new GregorianCalendar();
            checkin.set(year, Month, day);

            System.out.println("Date de Sortie? dd/MM/yyyy");
            date_sortiee = in.next();
            String[] test1 = date_sortiee.split("/");
            int day1 = Integer.parseInt(test[0]);
            int Month1 = Integer.parseInt(test[1]);
            int year1 = Integer.parseInt(test[2]);
            DateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            GregorianCalendar checkout= new GregorianCalendar();
            //System.out.println(format.format(checkin));
            checkout.set(year1, Month1, day1);


            checkdate(checkin,checkout);


            dateOK= checkdate(checkin, checkout);
            if (dateOK){
                error=false;
            }
            else{
                error=true;
            }
        }


public boolean checkdate(GregorianCalendar in,GregorianCalendar out){
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    GregorianCalendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
    System.out.println(format.format(in.getTime()));
    boolean test=false;
    if(in.before(out)&&in.after(today)|| in.before(out)&& in.equals(today)){
        System.out.println("puck u");
        test= true;

    }
    return test;
```

Comment: Your sample code contains a *lot* of pointless and distracting statements - including the two `DateFormat` variables which you never use. Then your `checkDate` method uses `mm` instead of `MM`, but we don't really know whether that's part of the problem. Please provide a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem. (I'd avoid parsing these values yourself, by the way.)

Comment: change `mm` to `MM`, and switch to using JodaTime.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `SimpleDateFormat` you create to do the parsing?  `checkin.parse(date_entree);`.

Answer (score 4):

In checkDate method change this

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

To

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

As you already know, `MM` is format for **Month** and `mm` is format for **minutes**, thus you get in appropriate results.

Comment: Date entrance:16/04/2013 date exit: 19/05/2013
result 16/05/2013 !

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean checkIfDateEntreeisok(Date date_entree, Date date_sortiee) throws ParseException{
    boolean dateOK=false;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Date todaysDate = new Date();
    if((date_entree.after(todaysDate)) || (date_entree.equals(todaysDate))) {
        System.out.println("first step");
        if ((date_entree.before(date_sortiee)) || (date_sortiee.equals(date_entree))) {
            System.out.println("second step");

            dateOK=true;
        }

    }

    else{
        System.out.println("les dates sont trop anciennes , veuillez les ressaisir");
    }
    return  dateOK;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [javadoc for Calendar.set(year, month, date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

You're effectively doing the following to parse the date:

```
int day = Integer.parseInt(test[0]);
int month = Integer.parseInt(test[1]);
int year = Integer.parseInt(test[2]);
GregorianCalendar checkin= new GregorianCalendar();
checkin.set(year, month, day);
```

(Month should not start with an uppercase letter btw)

... and if you read the javadoc then you'll see that the month is zero based in this method (January is 0) so things will be a little weird for you. e.g.:

- 1/1/2013 - would be 1st February 2013
- 31/12/2013 - would be 31st January 2014 (only 12 months in a year)
- 31/1/2013 - would be 3rd March 2013 (only 28 days in feb)

You can either do this:

```
checkin.set(year, month-1, day);
```

or (my preference) this:

```
checkin.setTime(format.parse(date_entree));
```

Additionally you should resolve the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14860758/669645) pointed out by @PermGenError